# How can I simulate worker threads in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, multithreading

I have a feature in which I have to receive items from different users (identified with some ID) and process them in relative order (so user A's item 1 is processed before user A's item 2, but no restriction on the order compared to user B's item N). In order to throughput I'd like to process them asynchronously.

I've done this with multithread languages and concurrent queues before, leaving the thread running in a busy wait if there wasn't anything in the queue anymore. But I don't know how I would solve this with JavaScript's single-thread. I was thinking about using Promises and an infinite loop inside, but I don't know if that's an anti-pattern.

As a restriction, my client is reticent to use external libraries that haven't been cleared by their audit team, so I'm trying to do this artisanally.

Thank you

Comment: JavaScript has [workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)

Answer (score 0):

You generally don't busy wait in JavaScript ever. But, many things that you can do (send a request to a web server, load an image (same thing as send a request to a web server, wait for user input) take a callback or return a promise (another form of a callback)

To process lists of asynchronous things is pretty easy with [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await)

```js
function doThing(thingMsg) {
  // this just represents some process that runs async
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
     const duration = Math.random() * 500 + 1500;  // 0.5 to 2 seconds
     setTimeout(() => {
       resolve(thingMsg);
     }, duration);
  });
}

const userAToDoList = [
  'mix flour',
  'knead',
  'bake',
  'slice',
];

const userBToDoList = [
  'chop',
  'fry',
  'braise',
  'combine',
];

async function doListInOrder(list, userName) {
  for (const item of list) {
    const result = await doThing(item);
    console.log(`${userName} did ${result}`);
  }
  console.log(`${userName} finished`);
}

doListInOrder(userAToDoList, 'userA');
doListInOrder(userBToDoList, 'userB');
```

Replace `doThing` with the things you want to do like "wait for a file to download", "wait for an image to download" or "wait for something from a worker" etc.